# Camel Processor not setting headers

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am not able to inject/modify headers in a processor using the below spring DSL config. Could you please help in figuring out what I am doing wrong?

```
    <routeContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    id="routes1">

    <route id="sdPoll" de:name="Polling"
        de:systemName="Polling" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="timer://sdPoll?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60000" />
        <process ref="refProcessor" />
        <to uri="http://dummyhost" />
        <to uri="log:DEBUG?showBody=true&amp;showHeaders=true" />
    </route>
</routeContext>
<bean id="refProcessor"
    class="com.abc.de.RefProcessor" />
```

Processor class

```
public class RefProcessor implements Processor {

private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RefProcessor.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", "TODO");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpUri", "http://localhost:8280/api/check");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    exchange.getIn().setBody("TODO");

    //exchange.getOut().setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
    //exchange.getOut().setHeader("Authorization", "TODO");
    //exchange.getOut().setBody("TODO");
 }
}
```

Logs-
Message History
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[sdPoll]            [sdPoll] [timer://sdPoll?fixedRate=true&period=60000                               ] [     21176]
[null]              [onCompletion1     ] [onCompletion                                                                  ] [       106]
[sdPoll]            [process7          ] [ref:refProcessor                                                      ] [     21067]
[null]              [process3          ] [ref:GenericErrorHandle                                                        ] [     21016]

Exchange[
        Id                  ID-ABC-63143-1516034486954-0-2
        ExchangePattern     InOnly
        **Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-ABC-63143-1516034486954-0-1, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, firedTime=Mon Jan 15 11:41:31 EST 2018}
        BodyType            null
        Body                [Body is null]**
]

Java DSL seem to work though! So what is wrong with my Spring DSL config

```
static RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder3() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("timer://timer1?period=60000").process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", "POST");
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpUri",
                            "http://localhost:8280/api/check");
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", "TODO");

                    exchange.getIn().setBody("TODO");
                }
            }).to("http://dummyhost").to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true");
        }
    };
}
```

Message History
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [timer://timer1?period=60000                                                   ] [        86]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [RefProcessorCamel$3$1@258e2e41                                        ] [         6]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [http://dummyhost                                                              ] [        76]

Exchange[
    Id                  ID-ABC-63940-1516036107063-0-2
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    **Headers             {Accept=application/json, Authorization=TODO, breadcrumbId=ID-ABC-63994-1516036220042-0-1, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpUri=http://localhost:8280/api/check, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, Content-Type=application/json, firedTime=Mon Jan 15 12:10:21 EST 2018}
    BodyType            String
    Body                TODO**
]

Comment: Did you declare your Processor as a spring bean? `<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.acme.MyProcessor"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Processor looks ok.

Just a wild guess, but do you use `routeContext` in your XML configuration intentionally? If not, can you try to switch to `camelContext`?

See http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/configuring-camel.html for the difference between `routeContext` and `camelContext`